# Retrofit Clients Sync and Async Implementations

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

Why not we make it as a standard to declare all Retrofit calls as async and if we need to add sync behavior then we can call from runBlocking block of the calling function.

Is there any issue with this approach.
I have use cases where I need sync calls as well as async calls. Is it good approach to declare only one suspend fun for both and then use kotlin to introduce sync behavior.

Comment: I don't see any issues, if anything you should consider if you can refactor your asynchronous calls to be executed exclusively in a coroutine context so `runBlocking` is not needed in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, if you're already using coroutines from the beginning, almost all of your logic code will be in coroutines anyway and you won't even need `runBlocking`. FYI, about terminology: suspend functions are also considered synchronous. I think you mean the term "blocking".